# Unwanted dot displaying in the documentation topic requests

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

In the Documentation topic request, after the user's reputation there is an unwanted dot is displaying.

Sample topic requests:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/topic-requests/23885
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/topic-requests/23891

In case if you are unable to see the dot (need sharp eye) in the topic request please inspect the element to see that.

[image: Inspect the element - topic requests]

Comment: Once that dot has been seen, it can never be unseen...

Comment: I believe it may be punctuation. Unfortunately, the padding/margin/whatever on the score makes it look a bit odd. Like when you end a sentence with `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in the next build, the trailing dot will be removed.

There are actually a bunch of variants of that string, depending on the state of the request user, but the `.` only made sense for a couple.